# What to call someone who is able to hold a conversation?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

So, think about being involved and present in the dialogue, but also someone who puts forward ideas and tries to look for ways to keep the conversation smooth and going, just like a flowing conversation. Who looks for solutions too and who is flexible to talk about something else.

Comment: Conversationalist

Answer (score 8):

> [con·ver·sa·tion·al·ist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conversationalist)
>   n.
>   One given to or skilled at conversation.
>   *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.*
>
> n
>   1. a person who enjoys or excels in conversation
>   *Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003*
>
> n.
>   a person who enjoys and contributes to good conversation.
>   [1830–40]
>   *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*

> [deipnosophist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deipnosophist)
>   n
>   1. (Rhetoric) a person who is a master of dinner-table conversation
>   [C17: from Greek deipnosophistai, title of a Greek work by Athenaeus (3rd century), describing learned discussions at a banquet, from deipnon meal + sophistai wise men; see sophist]
>   *Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003*

Answer (score 1):

**[Collocutor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Collocutor)**:  a person who talks or engages in conversation with another

**[Confabulator](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confabulator)**:  (someone who) To talk casually; chat.

**BARBER** :A brilliant conversationalist, who
occasionally shaves and cuts hair. Syn. for
Phonograph.-The foolish dictionary ... by Gideon Wurdz ... . Wurdz, Gideon, b. 1875. (Any dictionary dedicated to a dog is legit ;-)

Comment: Not to be confused with [Konfabulator](http://apple.wikia.com/wiki/Konfabulator).

Answer (score 0):

*Conversationalist* is the most obvious word.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conversationalist

Answer (score 0):

I'd call this person a pro-active communicator.

**proactive** |prōˈaktiv| adjective
(of a person, policy, or action) creating or controlling a situation by causing something to happen rather than responding to it after it has happened: be proactive in identifying and preventing potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use "raconteur" for someone who is especially good at telling stories.  Raconteurs are generally desired conversationalists, but do most of the speaking. A raconteur holds his interlocutor enthralled.

Example: "Mary Jane was a desired dinner guest because of her skills as a raconteur."

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/RACONTEUR