# What do you call someone who 'has' a non-material thing? (I.e. a conversation)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, word-usage

This question might seem slightly odd, since I'm trying to find a single word for a person who 'has' something yet does not necessarily own it.

Someone who *has* a house for example would be called an owner. However, someone who *has* a conversation does not necessarily own said conversation, yet still has it.

This is different from similar questions about possession/ownership since most of those questions refer to material things, in which case if one was in possession of something (i.e. a house) which doesn't necessarily belong to them you could simply refer to them as the 'holder' of said thing.
And although you could probably refer to someone as a 'conversation holder', it seems inappropriate given the context of what it means to *hold* something, which still implies possession of some sort.

I was dwelling on the possibility of a conversation *haver*, however that word does not exist as a noun derived from a verb in the way that: someone who holds would be a holder. (Someone who runs would be a runner, etc.) Why is it that the verb 'to have' cannot be translated in the same way into a noun?

**Those two men conversing at the table are conversation _________.**

Conversationalists? (this implies they must be good at or fond of conversing, which is not necessarily the case)

Simply 'talkers'? (talking and conversing are not the same thing though).

As I write this I notice that this might also have to do with our usage of the word conversation, for someone who *has* a thought is simply a thinker, and the same with most other verbs I can come up with.

I guess the term 'interlocutor' could work, however it still does not refer to the idea of having as possible noun...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not rephrase? Not all states of being are covered by nouns. You could say "**Those two men at the table are having a conversation**" or simply "**Those two men at the table are talking**" (which would be the most natural thing to say about them.

Comment: 'Have' is often used delexically as a main verb, as in 'She had a/n bath / drink /  discussion about curries / short nap / argument with her mother'. These are idioms, and are fixed to the extent that they resist passivisation (*_A bath was had by her_) and, as you say, conversion to an agent noun rewrite (*_She was a bath-haver_). As Robusto says, rephrasing is the solution (the active works fine for the first of my examples, and 'She was a regular bather' or 'She regularly took baths' for the second).

Comment: "Haver", meaning one who has, isn't very common but is on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haver#English) (sense 3). It might not have made other dictionaries but native speakers would have no trouble understanding a formulation like "conversation-haver". [Here is a usage of "conversation haver" from SF Gate](https://www.sfgate.com/bayarea/slideshow/The-worst-BART-passengers-you-encounter-every-day-126282.php).

Comment: related: [Conversationalist question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173107/what-to-call-someone-who-is-able-to-hold-a-conversation)

Answer (score 2):

The sense that you're using *have* is one of *participation*:

> **have** *verb*
>   4 Perform the action indicated by the noun specified (used especially in spoken English as an alternative to a more specific verb)
>   ‘I really enjoy having a good old blether with my pals and socialise with them when I get the chance.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have)

So you can call the people involved **participants**:

- Those two men conversing at the table are conversation *participants*.

Here's an example of this term used to describe people 'having' a race (something intangible):

- The Race Participant on leaderboards
  [- Running Room Ltd](https://runningroom.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/216402158-The-Race-Participant-on-leaderboards)

Comment: A cold participant (She has a cold)? An idea participant (He had an idea)? Problem participants (They have a problem)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Those are closer to ODO’s definition 2 - experience (though having a cold might perhaps stray into definition 1). They would need a different word. Maybe something like ‘subjects’ (of an experiment) or sufferers (of problems & colds, etc).